# Форма связи JQUERY AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, form

```
$("form").submit(function() { 
    var th = $(this);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "mail.php",
        data: th.serialize()
    }).done(function() {
        alert("Thank you!");
        setTimeout(function() {
            th.trigger("reset");
        }, 1000);
    });
    return false;
});
```

Есть скрипт для отправки формы, подскажите, как вместо алерта вывести скрытый див с благодарностями?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добавить на страницу тег div

```
<div id="hiddiv">Thank you!</div>
```

Добавить скрипт

```
$("form").submit(function() { 
    var th = $(this);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "mail.php",
        data: th.serialize()
    }).done(function() {
        $('#hiddiv').show();
        setTimeout(function() {
            th.trigger("reset");
        }, 1000);
    });
    return false;
});
```

Добавить в css

```
#hiddiv {
    display: none;
}
```